# Dependencies of a repackaged jar not working

Tags: java, maven, gradle, jar

I have the following dependency in my gradle file.

```
compile 'org.A:A:1.0'
```

which automatically pulls in

```
'org.B:B:1.0'
```

and many other jars which it depends on.
But,my project requires repackaged A.jar (let's call it A*.jar which I installed in a local maven repository as **custom** version).
So now I change the dependency as below

```
compile 'org.A:A:custom'
```

which doesn't pull in any of the dependencies mentioned in the pom.xml file present inside the A.
jar file (which it would, had it been org.A:A:**1.0**)

My questions are:

1) Based on what does the statement *compile org.A:A:1.0* pull other jars ? Is it pom.xml file present inside the jar?

2) What are the changes required if I want to automatically pull in both 'org.B:B:custom' and regular versions of other jars which are dependee of org.A:A:1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maven will read the pom file for the artifact it resolves as well. In there the dependencies are found and resolved.

You simply need to also upload the pom of A*.jar and modify the version of it accordingly to A* - that should already do the trick.